# java swing, simulate JTable terminateEditOnFocusLost behaviour

Tags: swing, jtable

```
putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean);
```

to make jtable end editing and clear current selected rows when it lose focus or when simply click over an other GUI component.
This is very useful, but with "terminateEditOnFocusLost" there are some strange behaviours if it is used with editCellAt and changeSelection.

There are also some undesiderable TableModelEvents fired for some fake table updates.

So, im looking for an hack to simulate "terminateEditOnFocusLost without using it, is this possibile?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hack at this moment. 
putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean) seem to be the only correct way.

Comment: I would like to use this functionality for some coloumns, for others not.

Comment: What helped me is reconfiguring it during the program's runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Overload the function to make it suit your needs.